# Display menu in footer but in header on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently in a situation where I have a header like so

```
<header class="container nav-container">
    <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

So it is essentially an empty header with nothing displayed.  Instead, for larger screens, the main navigation is actually displayed in the footer

```
<footer class="footer container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a title="Link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Link2" href="#">Link 2/a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Link3" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

At the moment, when I go down to mobile size, it displays the mobile nav button in the header as it should do.  However, when you click on it, it expands the menu in the footer.  Is there any way I can put the menu I am using in the footer to display in the header when on mobile size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind duplicating the footer html in the header you can do the following (I have a visible header Nav bar in the demo, but I assume you will tweak that):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container hidden-after-768">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a title="Link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a title="Link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a title="Link3" href="#">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<footer class="footer container hidden-before-767">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a title="Link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Link2" href="#">>Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Link3" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

With the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
  .hidden-after-768
  { 
    display: none; 
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px)
{
  .hidden-before-767
  { 
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

Here's a demo: http://www.bootply.com/render/4NgDES9hYq

(editable version http://www.bootply.com/4NgDES9hYq)

Note that theoretically you should just be able to do `<footer class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">`, and `<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">` for the header section, but I found there was a point between around 768 and 994 pixels where it showed neither the footer menu nor the hamburger button, so we were left with a dead spot with no navigation links whatsoever. That is why I created the extra `@media` classes.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
<header id="header_wrapper">
 <div class="container2">
                <div class="header_box">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav"> 
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</spaenter code heren> 
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse navStyle">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
                                <li>></li> 
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(window).width() <= 375){
 $('#navbar2').html($('#navbar').html())
 $('#navbar').html('')
}
else 
{
if($('#navbar2').length>1){
 $('#navbar').html($('#navbar2').html())
 $('#navbar2').html('')
 }
}});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<header class="container nav-container">
    <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
 
                <button button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbar2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="navbar2"></div>
     </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
<footer class="footer container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a title="Link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Link3" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use a jquery script to move the footer menu to the header menu in mobile view.

I created a temp div in header and adding the footer menu to that div and assigning the toggle menu to that div

Answer (score 1):

You can do this purely with bootstrap 'hidden-X' classes:

https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

I have made a codepen with an example of a duplicated menu that hides depending on the classes you give it:

https://codepen.io/c0un7z3r0/pen/NjrPvR

The magic works as follows:
Top menu container:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top hidden-lg" role="navigation">
```

Bottom menu container:

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" role="navigation">
```

note the hidden-X classes, these determine what circumstances each menu should be shown. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could also display your navigation with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. Just as a quick example :

```
.navigation {
  position: absolute; // in your header
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    position: static; // in your footer
  }
}
```